# 12V DC voltage drop for second switch 10 meters away

Tags: voltage

I have a ground floor main door lock operated by a solenoid (12W, 12 V), the switch (push button) of which is located at first floor, the power to this switch is given by an AC to DC(12V) adaptor - Now I have installed a second switch on second floor of my house (@ 10 meters away from first switch) & is connected to floor 1 switch in parallel (stair case wiring) having supply taken from same AC-to-DC adaptor - but due to voltage drop, the second floor switch is not operative.
Can this issue be resolved by using 'Boost Converter' - if yes, how it should be connected in given wiring set up ? 
Or is there any way to fix this - please help

Comment: This issue can be resolved by thicker wires. But first validate that your installation is actually doing what you expect it to do with shorter wires. This parallel setup sounds fishy to me.

Comment: Thanks. Its good idea to simulate it with shorter wires..I will try. thnx.

Comment: And take voltage measurements at the load for each switch. A current measurement for the working circuit would be nice too. (Just switch your multimeter to amps, connect the probes correctly and connect across the open switch. Don't forget to put the probes back in the V sockets when you're finished.) Add the findings into your question - or into an answer if you've solved it.

Answer (score 1):

At 12V 1 Amp, at 10 meters (20 round trip), the voltage drop would only be 1V or ~9% with 22 AWG wire. With 18 AWG wire it's only .42V or 3.5%. This shouldn't be enough to cause an issue with the solenoid. **If the solenoid is directly powered by the switch, and not with a controller.**

If directly powered, you could resolve this with a second power supply and a relay. The relay would be connected to the original switch with a short connection to reduce issues. The relay will also be low powered. With a smaller load, the length of wires is not as much of an issue, so the voltage drop will be smaller. Any common 12V automotive relay that has a 2 amp rating on it's switched side and ~200 mA or 0.2A on the coil side would work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDkszO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a boost converter is the answer you are looking for, since there should be a way to use the voltage you have.

If you are wiring the two switches in parallel, this is going to create a potentially unwanted scenario where you can only turn off the solenoid when *both* switches are turned off. Other factors not being taken into account include amount of wire you are running (the greater the length of wire, the more resistance you are adding), and the thickness of the wire you are using (thinner wire adds greater resistance also).

One way you could wire it (if you are interested in using light switches) is by using [three-way switches](https://www.familyhandyman.com/electrical/wiring-switches/how-to-wire-a-threeway-switch/view-all/).

First off, however, make sure the wire you are using is a thick enough gauge to handle the power. You could test your wiring setup closer to the solenoid to eliminate the possibility of the wire length, as another user suggested.

Comment: As I read it, the OP only has one solenoid, and is trying to add a second switch to control it.  If the current system is working, the power supply must be adequate, and he is losing voltage in the wiring to the second switch.

Comment: That is right - there is only one solenoid to operate - at present it operates by one switch at first floor - I am trying to add one more switch at second floor in the same circuit - so that I could be able to open my door (solenoid operative) from both the floors..

Comment: My mistake! Can I edit this answer to try and answer his actual question? Or should I make a new answer, or comment?

Comment: You can outright delete answers if you want.